# How to get a string using the _GET method?

Tags: php, redbean

How to get a string using the $_GET method? If get only ID, then it works well, example:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $id);
```

URL: **/page.php?id=1** — is working.

But, if using other columns, nothing happens. Example:

```
$id = $_GET['url'];
$posts = R::load('posts', $id);
```

**URL: /page.php?url=test** — Does not work. How to fix?

Comment: Are the 2 values ever on the same url?

Comment: please show how R::load() works -> right now I assume it only loads the id, you are not switching any column

Comment: Every value in the `$_GET` and `$_POST` arrays is already and always a string. What is happening that leads you to believe otherwise?

Comment: @MarkMueller no, 1 value

Comment: @vladislav_zp your $_GET are correct then. Please show us what is in R::load. The issue has to be in there.

Comment: @wodka Can you tell me what else can I use?

Comment: @MarkMueller What exactly to show?

Comment: Hold tight until someone with RedBean experience wants to answer this. Probably `R::find(…, "url = ?", …` or something for non-index lookups.

Comment: @vladislav_zp you'll have to tell us about the framework - or at least how the "R" lib is defined

Answer (score 0):

The value of `$_GET['url']` is a string itself. I think you should look into the `load` function which might only accept numeric values.

Comment: The «load»-function accepts only the ID. I tried other columns to set a numeric value. Does not help.

Comment: Then why do you want to pass `test` to that function which only accepts id?

Comment: That's I'm asking, what should I use to accept other columns?